# How to use WINAPI from newer SDK but still using the old SDK in WindowsMobile

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, windows-mobile, evc4

Specifically, I want to use Point-to-point Message Queue but because I am still using legacy codes in eVC++ 4 and it only support until PocketPC 2003SE SDK, I cannot find `CreateMsgQueue` and friends in the headers (the port to newer VisualStudio is still in progess)

I am using the Message Queue to do IPC with apps developed with WM-6.5-DTK (VS2005).

**Update:**
I am using the following code (taken from `msgqueue.h`) to store function pointers and load `CoreDLL.dll` using `GetProcAddress()` and `LoadLibrary()` respectively.

```
HANDLE /*WINAPI*/ (*CreateMsgQueue)(LPCWSTR lpName, LPMSGQUEUEOPTIONS lpOptions);
HANDLE /*WINAPI*/ (*OpenMsgQueue)(HANDLE hSrcProc, HANDLE hMsgQ
                  , LPMSGQUEUEOPTIONS lpOptions);
BOOL /*WINAPI*/ (*ReadMsgQueue)(HANDLE hMsgQ,
     /*__out_bcount(cbBufferSize)*/ LPVOID lpBuffer, DWORD cbBufferSize,
                LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead, DWORD dwTimeout, DWORD *pdwFlags);
BOOL /*WINAPI*/ (*WriteMsgQueue)(HANDLE hMsgQ, LPVOID lpBuffer, DWORD cbDataSize,
                DWORD dwTimeout, DWORD dwFlags);
BOOL /*WINAPI*/ (*GetMsgQueueInfo)(HANDLE hMsgQ, LPMSGQUEUEINFO lpInfo);

BOOL /*WINAPI*/ (*CloseMsgQueue)(HANDLE hMsgQ);
```

Is the above code alright since I need to comment out `WINAPI` and `__out_bcount(cbBufferSize)` in order for them to compile.

Comment: These were definitely available in the old PPC 2003 SDK - I've been using them for much longer than Studio has been used for developing device apps.  You're saying you don't have msgqueue.h or that the linker can't find them?

Comment: Uhm. shame on me. you are right! I actually didn't try to #include <msgqueue.h> since http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202792.aspx says "Requirement: Windows Mobile Version 5.0 and later"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [ctacke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13154/ctacke), it is actually available on PPC2003 SDK. The Requirement in the MSDN is wrong.

Btw, the above approach seems to work fine even after commenting out `WINAPI` and `__out_bcount(cbBufferSize)`